# Method dispose functionality C#

Tags: c#, dispose, filestream

Is there a way to dispose method variables without using try-finally block in C# 2010 (.Net 4)?

The story:
I have few files handler methods. Each handler (method) can abort in the middle of execution. 
I like to dispose all method's object before exiting the method.
The option to compose dispose method for each handler is not an option.

Thank you

This demonstrate the general idea:
`public static class Comparison
    {
        private static bool CompareXmls(...)
        {
            //has 7 object to be disposed in 3 exit points acordding to 4 conditions

```
        //General method flow:

        //1. init part of the object

        //2. if(!<condition1>)
                //disposed objects
                //exit method

        //3. perform some actions

        //4. init some of the other objects

        //2. if(!<condition2>)
                //disposed objects
                //exit method

        //and so on...
    }

    private static bool CompareJpgs(...)
    {
        //has 12 object to be disposed in 10 exit points acordding to 4 conditions
    }

    private static bool CompareBitMaps(...)
    {
        //has 5 object to be disposed in 3 exit points acordding to 4 conditions
    }

    private static bool CompareTxts(...)
    {
        //has 12 object to be disposed in 10 exit points acordding to 4 conditions
    }
}`
```

I have another 7 comparison methods

Comment: Why is it not an option?

Comment: Provide a sample please, and is it a class what you call method?

Comment: Would be good if you can put some code here otherwise there are way too many way to abstract out the disposing of handles...and yes, you have to create some abstraction to do so, it wont be done automatically

Comment: And what do you mean by "abort"?

Comment: Oded - This is not an option because I have far too many methods each of which has totally different objects.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`using`? Refer here for the full description on how and why to use http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh598w02(v=VS.100).aspx. A sample would be

```
using (MyDisposableType disposable1 = GetDisposable1(), disposable2 = GetDisposable2() /*,...*/)
{
    //your actions
}
```

after exiting from the `using` block, all disposable objects declared in its header will be disposed.

If your disposable objects are of different types, you can use nested `using`s:

```
using (MyDisposableType1 disposable1 = GetDisposable1())
{
    using (MyDisposableType2 disposable2 = GetDisposable2())
    {
        //more usings if needed, and then your actions
    }
}
```

Comment: Correction, all IDisposable-implementing objects will have their .Dispose() method called. Very useful in other cases than simply resource deallocation. =)

Comment: Right, that is more precise :)

Comment: But what about the non IDisposable objects?

Comment: Make them `IDisposable`, if possible. If not, collect them into `IDisposable` class, which disposes these objects in `Dispose` and use this new class in your methods. Possibly, you'll be able to come up with one or a little number of such classes which will cover the needs of all your different methods.

Comment: Generally, what do you mean by disposing something that is not `IDisposable`? It is a rule that if an object of a class can need additional cleaning on destroy (GC job is not enough), then the class should implement `IDisposable`. Your question makes me think that this rule is broken somewhere in your design. Microsoft and reliable third-party libraries do not break this rule, so I suppose you have control over your classes and therefore can make them `IDisposable`.

Answer (score 0):

I would put the method on an object that impiments [idisposible](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.idisposable.aspx) and call this.dispose() in a finally block

Comment: I do not want to use try-finally block.